# How can I use condition in Listview Component?

Tags: react-native

I need to use condition for change background `TouchableOpacity`. In outside of `Listview` condition working fine, but in `ListView` not working.

How can I **use condition** in `Listview`?

```
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          deliver:'',
        }
      }

      render() {
        return(
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={ (rowData)=>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={()=>this.setState({deliver:rowData})} 
                activeOpacity={0.5} 
                style={[styles.row, { backgroundColor: this.state.deliver === rowData ? '#0077FF' : '#eee'}]}>
                <Text>{rowData}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            }/>
         );
      }

      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
         row:{
           borderRadius:5,
           marginTop:5,
           paddingTop:5,
           paddingBottom:5
         },
      });
```

Comment: Really? Why -1 ??

Comment: Please manage a key value in array which is set into listview and change value in particular index of list. Issue because can call setState on click it will re render list view and all list view object are same.

Comment: @VishalDhanotiya I think rowData is like key value and when a rowData saving in a state conditions should be work but not working. I think problem is about states.

Comment: please check i have added example code i may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**:
Because `ListView`'s rows only rerender on their own if the `ListViewDataSource` has been changed, the `backgroundColor` won't update in this case.

As an aside, `ListView` is actually deprecated. `React Native` recommends using their `FlatList` or `SectionList`. [Read this for more info](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html)

The easiest way to get these rows to update is probably to just break the rows out into their own component.

Your `ListView` component would look like this:

```
      <ListView
        style={styles.container}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={rowData => <Row data={rowData} />}
      />
```

And your `Row` component would look like something this:

```
class Row extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { selected: false };
  }

  toggleSelected = () => {
    this.setState({ selected: !this.state.selected });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          backgroundColor: this.state.selected ? 'red' : 'yellow',
        }}
        onPress={this.toggleSelected}>
        <Text>{this.props.data}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/B1yLr2AO4) showing it in action! :)

**Original Answer:**

Looks like you might be using square brackets `[]` when you should be using curly brackets `{}`.

There are two ways to go about this.

1. Have 2 styles that you switch between. This is what you are trying to do, but the addition of the `[]` is tripping you up. `[]` brackets are only used when you want to feed in an *array* of styles. So in your case, this is what should work:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={ this.state.selected ? styles.selected : styles.unselected }
  onPress={...}
/>
```

2. Have one shared style and only change the `backgroundColor`. This method is a bit cleaner because there is less code repetition in styles. This is where you use the `[]` brackets, because we want to feed in an array of styles. As per RN's [style docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style), style elements in each index of the array will override style elements from the previous index. So to change only the `backgroundColor`, this is how you could do it.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={[styles.row, { backgroundColor: this.state.selected ? 'blue' : 'eee'}]}
  onPress={...}
/>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    backgroundColor:'white',
    borderRadius:5,
    marginTop:5
  },
});
```

Comment: sorry, always is #eee

Comment: Are you changing the state value the condition is tied to? In my example it’s this.state.selected but in yours it’s checking for this.state.deliver. If your onPress is working then the condition should work

Comment: Could you update your question with what your current code is? Then maybe I can help understand what is going wrong.

Comment: This is my current code. I save `rowData` value in `deliver` state and with this condition (`this.state.deliver === rowData`) I try to change background color.

Comment: I think conditions in style by states are not live, or use state like this is not true.

Comment: Problem is this: Condition not working in Listview!

Comment: Ahh I see. `ListView` row items will only rerender on their own if the `ListViewDataSource` has changed, which in your case it hasn't. Probably the easiest way to get the rows to update is to create a separate component for them. I will update my answer with some example code.

Answer (score 1):

I have added some example code on how to achieve conditionally styling in listview row click. I write basic code according to your requirement you can customize it. please check following code i have also added snack.expo.io so you can directly run into your device.

https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/listview

import * as React from 'react';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

```
// You can import from local files
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      data: this._genRow(),
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this._genRow()),
    }
  }

  _genRow(){
    var datas = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      datas.push({
        row: i,
        isSelect: false,
      });
    }
    console.log('datas ' + JSON.stringify(datas));
    return datas;
  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.data)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow = {this._renderRow.bind(this)}
        renderHeader = {() => <View style={{height: 10, backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'}} />}
        onEndReached = {() => console.log('')}
        renderSeparator = {(sectionID, rowID) =>
          <View
            style={styles.style_separator}
            key={`${sectionID} - ${rowID}`}
          />}
      />
    );
  }

  _renderRow(rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {
    console.log('render row ...');
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressRow.bind(this, rowID, rowData)}>{rowData.isSelect ?
        <View style={styles.style_row_view}>
          <Text style={styles.style_text}>{rowData.row}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.style_text}>{rowData.isSelect ? 'true' : 'false'}</Text>
        </View>

        :
        <View style={styles.style_row_view1}>
          <Text style={styles.style_text}>{rowData.row}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.style_text}>{rowData.isSelect ? 'true' : 'false'}</Text>
        </View>
        }
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

  _onPressRow(rowID, rowData) {
  rowData.isSelect = !rowData.isSelect;
    var dataClone = this.state.data;
    dataClone[rowID] = rowData;
    this.setState({
      data: dataClone
    });
    console.log(this.state.data);
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  style_row_view: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 57,
    backgroundColor: '#FF0',
  },style_row_view1: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 57,
    backgroundColor: '#0FF',
  },
  style_text: {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 12,
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#333333',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },

});
```